# Echo php in php?

Tags: php

I would like to insert a PHP tag within a PHP tag in the example below:

```
<?php $values = get_field('sold');
if($values)
{ foreach($values as $value) {echo '<div id="sold">'; echo $value; echo '</div>'; } } 
else {
echo '<div id="inquire"><a href="mailto:jack@domain.com?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>">Inquire about this item...</a></div>';
}
?>
```

I would like to imprint `the_title();` as the subject of the email.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: You can concatenate strings and variable with a dot (.) . So `{echo '<div id="sold">'; echo $value; echo '</div>'; }` can be `{echo '<div id="sold">'.$value.'</div>'; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the title is the return value of a php function you can just call the function and concatenate it to the rest of the echo.
For example

```
echo '<div id="inquire"><a href="mailto:jack@domain.com?subject=' . the_title() . '">Inquire about this item...</a></div>'
```

Comment: Thank you. That works although for some reason it is outputting the title before the link. Any idea as to why that is happening?

Comment: does the function the_title() contain an echo?

Comment: No. Actually, it doesn't work. What happening is it is outputting it above the link and the subject is blank.

Comment: This worked:

echo '<div id="inquire"><a href="mailto:jack@domain.com?subject=';
echo '' . the_title() . '';
echo '">Inquire about this item...</a></div>';

Comment: I'm glad that worked. I haven't figured out why the other code wouldn't work, since concatenation is evaluated first when you perform an echo. However apparently you can give the echo statement commas to echo each value individually, so `echo '<div id="inquire"><a href="mailto:jack@domain.com?subject=',  '' . the_title() . '' ,  '">Inquire about this item...</a></div>'; ` is theoretically the same as your solution.